# Delete Particular Id From Column using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Two tables named are image and product the structure of the tables are as below

**Table : Image**

```
image_id    image_path  image
  1          ./images/   aaa
  2          ./images/   bbb
  3          ./images/   ccc
```

**Table : Product**

```
product_id   product_gallery
  1           1,2
  2           3,1
  3           1,2,3
```

Now I want to remove the image from image table image_id = 3

While I'm deleting image id 3 from image table, at the same time product table product gallery column containing the id 3 will be deleted.

For example

Expected output :

```
   product_id   product_gallery
      1           1,2
      2           1
      3           1,2
```

I don't have any idea for this but I can delete the images as of now, still I want to delete image id from the product table.

Comment: Never use comma separated values as link between 2 tables! Use a 3-rd table, linking images and products with foreign keys.

Comment: hope you need to learn database normalization ....

Comment: That will soon become a rolling snowball mess!

Comment: any solution for my question

Comment: @AaruKarthiga you have got correct advice above, but if you are desperate for an answer the you can use REPLACE keyword in MYSQL.  `UPDATE table tablename SET product_gallery = REPLACE(product_gallery,'your_deleted_image_id','')` But i won't suggest this

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have a 3-rd table , some thing like :

**Table : product-gallery**

```
   product_id   image_id
      1           1
      1           2
      2           1
      3           1
      3           2
```

In this way, working with database would be as easy as abc :)

But if you want to go your way, you have to deal with some sql or php processing functions.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is better if you change the way your product table was constructed.. it would give you a hard time retrieving and manipulating it.. try using this format:

```
id product_id product_gallery
1    1          1
2    1          2
3    2          1
```

etc etc...